# Database Design For Employee Business Hours

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a simple employee database (I use mySql):

```
Employee (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  email_Id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  mobile_Number varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY employee_email_id_unique (email_Id)
)
```

Now I need to store different Business Hours for every employee

- All Monday, 9am to 5pm
- All Tuesday, day-off
- All Wednesday, 9am to 5pm
- All Thursday, 9am to 5pm
- All Friday, 9am to 5pm
- All Saturday, 9am to 3pm
- All Sunday, day-off

**Method 1:** Store open_time and close_time for every day of week if open_time and close_time is null then its is day-off

```
Employee_Business_Hours (
  id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_id varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  day_of_week varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  open_time time NULL,
  close_time time NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),KEY employee_id_foreign (emp_id),
  CONSTRAINT employee_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES Employee (id)
)
```

**Method 2:** Store open_time and close_time for every day of week with is_day_off flag

```
Employee_Business_Hours (
  id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  emp_id varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  day_of_week varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  open_time time NOT NULL,
  close_time time NOT NULL,
  is_day_off tinyint(1) NOT NULL, /*boolean value*/
  PRIMARY KEY (id),KEY employee_id_foreign (emp_id),
  CONSTRAINT employee_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES Employee (id)
)
```

**Method 3:** if day-off then Do not store in Employee_Business_Hours table

```
Employee_Business_Hours (
 id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 emp_id varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 day_of_week varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 open_time time NOT NULL,
 close_time time NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),KEY employee_id_foreign (emp_id),
 CONSTRAINT employee_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES Employee (id)
)
```

Which Method is best here, or maybe there is another way?